# Show specific category posts on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show specific category posts on homepage, I am using Custom post type 'reviews'. Here is the query below:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'posts_per_page'  => $nos_brand, 
        'post_type'       => 'reviews', 
        'order'           => 'ASC', 
        'orderby'         => 'menu_order', 
        'category_name'   => 'Free sites'
    )
);
```

I don't know what its not showing data on specific category. Can you please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Il will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with the id param ?

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( 
      array(
         'posts_per_page' => $nos_brand, 
         'post_type' => 'reviews',
         'order' => 'ASC', 
         'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
         'cat' => '10' // Your category id
       ) 
);
```

Comment: Hi I have tried but still not showing category data :(

Comment: I am using PostMash Custom Plugin for ordering category posts

Comment: Hmm maybe it has something to do with the plugin. Can  you try deactivating it and try again?